Navigation break through the wall
I'm using Yahboom rosmaster x3 and when I navigation my robot go break through the wall but real robot actually fine
https://youtube.com/shorts/Q_RixS36mzI?si=TtUXcPVYahAJSvGe

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From the video you sent, it seems like your robot's odometry is being calculated or gathered incorrectly, as it is telling your robot that is has moved like on the RVIZ screen, while in reality it is traveling straight. I would look at how you gather your odometry ex (Wheel encoders, IMU) and check for errors there, and also see if your sampling rate is adequate.
Since you are using a mechanum drive, if you are using wheel encoders, those not being set up properly could cause the sideways odom movement we're seeing.
